# Keep modal window open when reCAPTCHA not ticked in drupal form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, recaptcha

I have a drupal 7 webform in a modal, but if you don't tick "I am not a robot", it closes the modal and post the form, error returning from post. Is there a way we can keep the modal open if not ticked?

Thanks

Comment: You might find better support on the Drupal StackExchange site or Drupal Slack.

Comment: Yes, in javascript you can prevent the form from being submitted depending on the checkbox state.